# this.props.fetch user is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { NavigationContainer, TabActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { fetchUser } from "../redux/actions";
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

import FeedScreen from "./main/Feed";
import ProfileScreen from "./main/Profile";
import AddScreen from "./main/Add";

export class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Feed"
          component={FeedScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Add"
          component={AddScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-box" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="account-circle"
                color={color}
                size={26}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
});
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(Main);
```

this is my code and I am very confused it says that its imported but fetchUser is not being read.

im trying to export it from this file

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants/index";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

export function fetchUser() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("user")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          dispatch({ type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data() });
        } else {
          console.log("does not exist");
        }
      });
  };
}
```

if someone can please help. I have been stuck on this for days

I have tried searching forums and have found nothing. I went through the course again and still nothing I am currently working on this to meet a deadline for an important project and I have not been able to come to a solution. I have all the necessary packages installed, but still no dice. The source code did not help much either, so if anyone can hep it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see where you import something called `fetchUser`, but I don't see where you pass it to the component as a prop.  (And, if you do, why also import it?)  Can you indicate specifically *why* you expect `this.props.fetchUser` to be a function?

Comment: You don't use your action creator in `mapDispatchToProps`, so it won't be passed to your component as a prop. Look into the documentation for mapDispatchToProps https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Answer (score 0):

Try having your mapDispatchToProps like this:

```
    const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => ({ fetchUser: () => fetchUser()(dispatch) });
```

Here's the full file with the change applied:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { NavigationContainer, TabActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { fetchUser } from "../redux/actions";
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

import FeedScreen from "./main/Feed";
import ProfileScreen from "./main/Profile";
import AddScreen from "./main/Add";

export class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Feed"
          component={FeedScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Add"
          component={AddScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-box" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="account-circle"
                color={color}
                size={26}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
});
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => ({ fetchUser: () => fetchUser()(dispatch) });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(Main);
```